# w3wp terminated due to stack overflow

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, w3wp

I'm having trouble tracking down what's causing W3WP.exe to fail with a stack overflow.

I've looked at this question: [How to debug: w3wp.exe process was terminated due to a stack overflow (works on one machine but not another)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053708/how-to-debug-w3wp-exe-process-was-terminated-due-to-a-stack-overflow-works-on)

It would be great except that there's no memory dump and I have no idea why. I see a series of Report folders in the ReportQueue but all they have is two files. `Report.WER` and `WERB0CD.tmp.version.txt` neither of which contain any further information.

I've tried to determine if it's in another location per this question: [A process crashed in windows .. Crash dump location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263813/a-process-crashed-in-windows-crash-dump-location)
But it points to an MSDN article which states the default values can be found here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps

When I look at my registry there is no LocalDumps key.

Not really sure what to do now since it seems I have no information which can point me to the cause of the crash. Does anyone have any additional recommendations?

Comment: This article might be of help to enable the LocalDumps key yourself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335678/how-to-debug-w3wp-clr-dll-error/18335759#18335759